# Running a Matlab script in Unix

Tags: macos, matlab, shell, unix, terminal

I have very little Unix knowledge so please be gentle with me (or give suggestions where to look for answers). I have been trying to find a solution online but I got stuck so that's why I am turning to this page.
So I ran Matlab scripts before in the Unix shell (on Mac OS X) but unfortunately now it doesn't seem to work. I use the following command to run a function with certain input parameters:

`nohup nice matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "run ModelWSSim(100000,150,0.25,2.5,10,1)" 2>&1'`

The function works perfectly on my mac with these input parameters so I suspect the function is ok. When I execute this command in the terminal shell it creates an output log nohup.out entailing the output while running the function (it should only output a few dots). The problem  is that for some reason nohup.out grows really fast right after executing, but I can't seem to open it since it is such a big file. I remember running functions like this in the past so I can't be far off, anyone has any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: use `tail -f nohup.out` to monitor the output. What happens if you skip the "nice nohup" part?

Comment: Ok, that got me these different warnings, both flooding the file: Bad file descriptor
 reading character from command line 
Warning: Error reading character from command line

Comment: It is unbelievable that your shell accepted the command with an unbalanced `'` at the end.